# PHP autoload debugging with and without composer

Tags: php, spl-autoloader

Having spent more than 2 hours trying to debug an autoload issue in PHP that was caused by a spelling mistake.

Is there a way to show what file PHP will look for when trying to load a particular class?
Looking for something that will take into account the namespaces of the current file and any spl_autoload / composer settings.

So something like the following can be inserted into a script to help debugging :

```
var_dump(showAutoLoadPaths('myspace\Controller\fancyClass'));
$template = new myspace\fancyClass;
```

and get an output like :

```
array (
    0 => 'src/myspace/Controller/fancyClass',
)
Undefined class : fancyClass
```

allowing my to run :

```
ls -la src/myspace/Controller/fancyClass
ls: cannot access 'Controller': No such file or directory
ls -la src/myspace
drwxrwxr-x 1 user user 74 May 21 15:47 Controllers
```

As can be seen from the above, PHP is looking for a folder 'Controller' but the folder is actually called 'Controllers'!

I have tried to interpret the output from spl_autoload_functions() but i cant work out what is what in the file.
Any suggestions for existing/built in solutions would be great, but if none exist, any hints on decoding the spl_autoload_functions output so i can write something myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can see more info about autoloaders in `PSR-0` and `PSR-4` patterns.

Basically, if you have autoload folder registered, they will call `spl_autoload_register()` function so, you can try search inside your directory if you find something with this function and get a debug

Look [here](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) about autoload patterns. You probably have an `autoload()` function that you can check the folders that are set.

And look [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to see more about the autoloader.